Catch unhandled exception in NodeJs child process
My NodeJs app forks 10 child processes on the start.
In every child process I have the next code:
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    log.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
}).on('message', (message: any) => {
    if (message.type === 'error') {
        log.error(`Message error event: ${message}`);
    }
})
.on('uncaughtException', (err: any) => {
    log.error('Uncaught Exception thrown', err);
    log.error(err.stack);

    process.exit(1);
}).on('SIGINT', async () => {
    log.info('SIGINT signal received.');

    process.exit(0); 
}).on('exit', async (code) => {
    log.info(`Process exit with code: ${code}`);

    process.exit(code);
});

My problem is when unhandled exception happens it doesn't catch it.
If I deploy my app via pm2 - I can see nothing only Forked 432637 is exited with code 1 that I catch in the parent process code:
forked.on('exit', (code) => {
    log.error(`Forked ${forked.pid} is exited with code ${code}. Restarting... in ${RESTART_TIMEOUT_IN_MILISECONDS} ms`);
});

If I deploy my app like npm run start then I see the next error:
TypeError: this.log is not a function
    at Logger.<computed> (/home/myapp/node_modules/log4js/lib/logger.js:235:10)
    at Client.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:395:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)

But I know it is not related to logs.
How can I catch this unhandled error? Preferable solution when I deploy via pm2.

What is "npm run start" and pm2 entry point? "But I know it is not related to logs" - can you clarify? Are you using log4js? Then the error is caused by it, probably when it tried to log another error and failed to do this

In past I already had this error and it was that I didn't catch an error from promise - in this case it showed me the same error with logs, but it wasn't related to it at all.  What do you mean on entry point? It starts the parent process that forks to 10 child processes

I mean that if an error is caused by your logger, whatever log is this, you won't see the real error from unhandled rejection. So it matters how log4js is related to your project

I use "log4js": "^6.9.1". What else can be useful here?

Is "log" an instance of log4js? The lib needs to be debugged to determine what could cause this error. I don't see how this could be possible from here https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/lib/logger.js#L235 . The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and a way to reproduce, otherwise this can be done on your side only. Meanwhile I'd suggest to replace log with a dummy object that is equal to console or wraps around its methods depending on how you used log. This would help to narrow down the problem to log4js and get a quick fix if you need it

Yes, it is a log4js instance. How can I wrap it?

Make a dummy instance like const log = console or customize it based on your primary needs const log = { info(...args) { if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') console.log('[info]', ...args) ... }, if this solves the problem then the cause is certainly in log4js

Ok. My answer will take time since I need to do it on production environment. Thanks
